# How to show only selected dates and disable all other dates in fullcalendar.io ( JavaScript calendar )

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar

I am using the JavaScript calendar https://fullcalendar.io/.
and want to show only selected dates and disable all other dates.

I tried using "validRange" which accepts only start and end, but it doesn't accept array of dates.

Please help

following is my code

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/fullcalendar/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/fullcalendar/main.js"></script>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                // right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
                right: 'dayGridMonth'
            },
            
            initialDate: '<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>',
            navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            businessHours: true, // display business hours
            editable: true,
            selectable: true,

            validRange:{
                
                
                start:'2022-08-27',
                end:'2022-08-30',

                
            },

            // events: []
            events: <?php echo $event; ?>
            
        });
        calendar.render();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If you only show days where events occur, then that, by implication, highlights them compared to the others. Are you then saying that new events can only be added onto dates where events already exist? Well yes you can't do that with validRange, it's true. You'd need some custom code I think to compare the selected date range with the list of events and see if the dates match.